# What is the meaning of "Put together 'f****ing sh*t' ~" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, slang, emphasis

What is the meaning of "Put together 'f****ing sh*t' is ~" in the following sentence?

> **Put together 'f****ing sh*t' is** stuff that really bothers, angers, or disgusts you.

(Source: [Meaning of "Don't settle for no f-ing s#*t"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203192/dont-settle-for-no-fucking-shit-what-does-that-mean))

1. Does it mean "That we put together 'f****ing sh*t' is stuff that really bothers, angers, or disgusts you"?

There is another verb (->is) after the sentence that starts with the verb(->Put).
  2. Is it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Put" is the past participle of "Put". You can understand the line as

> If they are put together ...

There is a modifying participle phrase. Compare:

> Eaten quickly, burgers are delicious.

The sentence still needs a grammatical subject, and a participle phrase cannot be a subject.  In my example, "burgers" is the subject. In your example, the quote is the grammatical subject. A participle isn't a noun phrase, but a quote can be.

Comment: If so, can a sentence starting with a past participle be a subject of sentences? for example, is a sentence," Eaten quickly are~" possilbe? If possilbe, how are these sentences like that interpreted? (Put together ...is ->If they are put together ...:;  Eaten quickly are ~ -> If they are eaten quickly are~ ) ?